# Threejs How to Transform a Vector3?

Tags: javascript, matrix, three.js

I'm trying to make bones and then transform the vertices of each bone, but I can't figure out what syntax I need to use. For example I tried:

```
var v = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0);
var b = new THREE.Bone();
b.position.x = 5;
b.position.y = 5;
b.position.z = 5;
b.updateMatrix();
v.applyMatrix4(b.matrixWorld);
console.log(v);
```

Expecting the new coordinates of vector v to be (5,5,5), however the console.log output is (0,0,0). Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [THREE.Object3D](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Object3D):
`updateMatrix()` updates the local transformation (`Object3D.matrix`), but `updateMatrixWorld()` update the global transform of the object and its children (`Object3D.matrix` and `Object3D.matrixWorld`).

This means, that you either have to use the `Object3D.matrix` property:

```
b.updateMatrix();
v.applyMatrix4(b.matrix);
```

Or you have to `updateMatrixWorld()`:

```
b.updateMatrixWorld();
v.applyMatrix4(b.matrixWorld);
```

Comment: Thanks! That finally gave me the output I was looking for. It also helped me work with the other problem I was wondering about of how to do bones with parents.
```
    var v = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0);
    var p = new THREE.Bone();
    p.position.x = 5;
    p.position.y = 5;
    p.position.z = 5;
    p.updateMatrix();
    p.updateMatrixWorld();
    var b = new THREE.Bone();
    b.position.x = 5;
    b.position.y = 5;
    b.position.z = 5;
    p.add(b);
    b.updateMatrix();
    b.updateMatrixWorld();
    v.applyMatrix4(b.matrixWorld);
    console.log(v);
```
Does the the job